# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

In my application I use `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")` to get SHA1, it can run successfully in android 2.3, but it can't run in android 4.0 and it will show the below exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.security.MessageDigest
 at com.screenshare.email.Utility.getConsistentDeviceId(Utility.java:597)
 at com.screenshare.exchange.SyncManager.getDeviceIdInternal(SyncManager.java:1079)
 at com.screenshare.exchange.SyncManager.getDeviceId(SyncManager.java:1045)
 at com.screenshare.exchange.SyncManager.onCreate(SyncManager.java:1813)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Who can explain this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [reading around googlegroups](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/google-maps-for-mobile/KinrGn9DcIE) it sounds like `android.security.MessageDigest` was removed in Honeycomb.  Unfortunately I am yet to find evidence of this in the Android developer documentation.

Try using [`java.security.MessageDigest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The solution is right, it can make my application run successfully in 4.0 after change to "java.security.MessageDigest".

Comment: how are you going to change that if it's in the Google Add on SDK?